# TypeError: Could not convert group to numeric

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

I am going through Krish Naik's "End To End ML Project With Deployment" course on YouTube. Right now, I am in Tutorial 3. Here is [the link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqqGdu1P2FM&list=PLZoTAELRMXVPS-dOaVbAux22vzqdgoGhG&index=5).

I am facing an issue with **BIVARIATE ANALYSIS ( Is gender has any impact on student's performance ? )** while performing Exploratory Data Analysis. Here is [the link to the file on GitHub](https://github.com/krishnaik06/mlproject/blob/main/notebook/1%20.%20EDA%20STUDENT%20PERFORMANCE%20.ipynb).

When I run this code:
[image]

I get this error:
[image]

How can I fix it?